# Laravel 5.2 - How to update "updated_at" field with UTC timestamp?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 (on PHP version 7) and below is the update query I'm running:

```
$data=DB::table('posts')
                        ->where("id", $post_id)
                        ->update(
                            array(
                                'title'         =>      $request['title'],
                                'body'          =>      $request['body'],
                                'slug'          =>      str_slug($request['title']),
                                'updated_at'    =>      DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
            ));
```

The "updated_at" field updated with the current time. But I want to update it with the UTC timestamp. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don’t need to manually set the `updated_at` value; Eloquent sets it for you with the current UTC timestamp when calling `update()`.

Comment: @MartinBean I have checked the record from mysql and I saw that 'updated_at' not changed if I used update().

Comment: Sorry, just realised you’re using the `DB` façade and not an Eloquent model. I’d create a `Post` model for your posts (if you haven’t already)—it’ll make your life much simpler than working with database schemas directly.

Comment: @MartinBean - Can you please post the model as your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `model->save()` method it should handle created and updated dates for you. In general you should not need to do raw DB updates in Laravel.

If you wish to have a different timezone for this then look at the timezone setting in app.php. The default however is 'UTC' so you should not have to worry.